# What is systemd-networkd.socket in Ubuntu WSL?

Tags: systemd, windows-subsystem-for-linux

While I am installing Ubuntu 20.10 in Windows Subsystem for Linux I got the following error :

```
Failed to get load state of systemd-networkd.socket: Connection timed out
Failed to try-restart systemd-networkd.service: Connection timed out
See system logs and 'systemctl status systemd-networkd.service' for details.
```

I am following this [Tutorial](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/installing-ubuntu-20-10-on-wsl/18941). And I know that Ubuntu 20.10 for WSL is not *Normal* WSL Distribution. I am using first method in the tutorial which is `sudo sed --in-place 's/focal/groovy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` then update then upgrade.

What does that error mean or how can I solve it?

Comment: Note that WSL does not support systemd, so anything that depends on it will fail.  How are you going about installing 20.10 in WSL?  That's not a "normal" WSL distribution, so it  requires some extra work.  An (apparently now former) Canonical employee (I believe he was the/a Community Manager) posted [this](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/installing-ubuntu-20-10-on-wsl/18941) about upgrading to 20.10 on WSL.  Is that what you are using?  If so, which method of the ones provided?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for your reply. but actually this is the tutorial that I am following. And I know that Ubuntu 20.10 for WSL is not *Normal* WSL Distribution. I am using first method in the tutorial which is `sudo sed --in-place 's/focal/groovy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` then update then upgrade.

Comment: Cool - That's information you should edit/add to your question.  Without it, anyone would just be guessing on what you are doing.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I have updated question. :)

Comment: Thanks - Is there any more context around the error?  Is that the first thing that happens on the `sudo apt -y upgrade`, or does the error occur during the upgrade of some particular package?  I just created an Ubuntu 20.04 clean install on WSL, then followed the same directions, and I don't have any error.  That's why I'm wondering if it's a particular package in your installation.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Yes, when I upgrade. but actually I think the problem is solved when I installed `systemd` clean Installation Ubuntu 20.04 and I am didn't meet error. :)